# How do I store the LinkedIn API AccessToken so I don't have to re-enter credentials every time I use the LinkedIn API?

Tags: c#, oauth, linkedin-api

I am writing an app to mine information from [LinkedIn](http://linkedin.com).
I've [only found one code sample](http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1190) thus far on oAuth. I'm having trouble understanding the workflow of oAuth, for example:

1. The Example asks for the `Username/Password` combination to log into LinkedIn and return a token, but in my case, I will always use the same LinkedIn Account.

Since I'm always going to be using the same user to access the LinkedIn API, is there a way to do it so I don't have to re-enter the user name and password for every access request? The facebook API allows me to set the Token to not expire, thereby allowing me to save this token as an `Attribute` inside my application).

The idea is :

1. Get a token for a certain LinkedIn Account
2. Store it in my app hardcoded, since this is the only account I will be using the retrieve information from LinkedIn.
3. Make API Calls using this token, everytime I need it
4. Parse the JSON/XML file

How do I do this in C#?

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeStocker for making my Thread Clearer and the Tittle Better :)

Comment: You can hard-code an auth token into your app, but then your app will only work for 24 hours (or whatever expiration period LinkedIn uses - 24 hours is typical). What your app needs to do is to log in with a username and password and get back an OAuth token which is then saved in memory and used to access the LinkedIn API. Your app should continue to reuse this particular response until you happen to get an authentication failure with it (this means it has expired), at which point your app should go fetch a new token.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I store the LinkedIn API AccessToken so I dont have to re-enter credentials every time I use the LinkedIn API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504482/how-do-i-store-the-linkedin-api-accesstoken-so-i-dont-have-to-re-enter-credentia)

Comment: It seems you know what do. Why don't you do it? What part do you have problems with?

Comment: I dont know how to use the API, i am still studying it and running some tests.

But,the main point is that, i dont WANT the user to hit the "OK I ACCEPT USING THIS" button, got it ? The idea is to use always the same username/password, without prompting for any user input,since i plan to use it as an automated process

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins Oauth is all about letting the customers choose which applications can see which bits of their data, so they have to approve the access to act on their behalf - it is done in this manner to avoid phishing sites looking like LinkedIn, then actually giving back similar results, but sending off emails to all of your contacts recommending a new generic sexual health drug/genuine reproduction watch/etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to determine the member token, and the corresponding OAuth token -- you could do this as a one off, and LinkedIn have some [quite good documentation about authorizing](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) (along with links to tools to verify, and to libraries that you can use to simplyify matters)

Once you have those, it's just a case of storing them "somewhere safe" - there is even a clause in the [LinkedIn APIs Terms of Use](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use) that permits storage:

> You may store the Member Token and the OAuth Token until the earlier of:
>
> - Your ceasing using the APIs;
> - The LinkedIn user uninstalls your application or directs you to delete the user's information; or,
> - We terminate your use of them for breach of these Terms.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be exceptionally clear - what you need to store on your system is the OAuth access token for that member. So you will need to store that token along with the userID (just so you can remember who that token belongs to). That token, along with your API key and secret, should give you the ability to call the linkedin services.

Answer (score 1):

There's a complete `oAuth` ASP.NET + C# code example download available in the first post of the thread here:

- https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1230

You might also find the LinkedIn Toolkit to be of some help:

- http://linkedintoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks @Cory but this is the same core lib i´ve posted on my Question.
Fatih Yasar is the only user that posted an example online,and this only example,is avaible everywhere you look after another one =/